# highcharts bar chart: columns width is very thin

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Columns are very thin in my [highcharts](http://www.highcharts.com/) bar chart. It's not calculating the width automatically. It's not taking the maximum portion of the grid for that related series.
http://jsfiddle.net/akshayasharma/WLCzS/28/

```
$(function () {
    var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'container',
            type: 'column'
        },
        xAxis: {
            type: "category"
        },

        series: [{
            name: "a",
            data: [{x: 0, y: 70}]
        }, {  
            name: "b",
            data: [{x: 1, y: 29}]
        },
        {     
            name : "c",
            data: [{x: 2, y: 29}]
        },
        {           
            name : "d",
            data: [{x: 3, y: 29}]
        }, {            
            name : "e",
            data: [{x: 4, y: 29}]
        },
        {           
            name : "f",
            data: [{ x: 5, y: 29}]
        }
        ]
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Your series are grouped by default, you can disable grouping with:

```
plotOptions: {
    column: {
        grouping: false,
    }
},
```

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/vwbwn1gz/

Answer (score 1):

Your assumption "Its not taking the maximum portion of the grid for that related series" is not correct. In fact it is maximizing the column width but you did not provide every value for your series. So you have a lot of columns with a height of 0.

As you build up your example you have to provide an `x:0`, `x:1`, `x:2` etc. value for every series. See this extension to your sample where I provide `x:0` values for every series:

```js
$(function () {
    var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'container',
            type: 'column'
        },
        xAxis: {
            type: "category"
        },
        
        series: [{
            name: "a",
            data: [{x: 0, y: 70}]
        }, {  
            name: "b",
            data: [{x: 0, y: 65},{x: 1, y: 29}]
        },
        {     
            name : "c",
            data: [{x: 0, y: 60},{x: 2, y: 29}]
        },
        {           
            name : "d",
            data: [{x: 0, y: 55},{x: 3, y: 29}]
        }, {            
            name : "e",
            data: [{x: 0, y: 50},{x: 4, y: 29}]
        },
        {           
            name : "f",
            data: [{x: 0, y: 45},{ x: 5, y: 29}]
        }
        ]
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/2.3.2/highcharts.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="height: 400px"></div>
```

Maybe you want something like this:

```js
$(function () {
    var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'container',
            type: 'column'
        },
        xAxis: {
            type: "category"
        },
        
        series: [{
            colorByPoint: true,        
            data: [{
                name: "a",
             y: 70
              },{  
                name: "b",
             y: 29
              },{     
                name : "c",
             y: 29
              },{           
                name : "d",
                y: 29
              }, {
                name : "e",
             y: 29
              }
           ]
        }]
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/2.3.2/highcharts.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="height: 400px"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer by @gus27 is a good one, but I'll put this out as another alternative, and further explanation.

`grouping` is `true` by default, and when you put multiple series on a column/bar chart, the assumption is that you intend to group them.

Therefore, it leaves space at each `x` value on the axis for a column from each series (the `0` value volumns that gus mentioned).

If you are not trying to make a chart with grouped columns, you can either

1) Put all your data into a single series (as previously answered)

2) set `grouping` to `false` in your `plotOptions`:

```
plotOptions: {
  series: {
    grouping: false
  }
}
```

Fiddle:

- http://jsfiddle.net/WLCzS/30/

Comment: thanks jlbriggs, stpoa and gus27. This grouping optiong worked for me.

Comment: @ak_delhi if the answer solved your problem, please consider accepting and voting for it. thanks!